# How to test if a UIButton title is nil

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a twitterlogeout button when the user sucessfully logs in the username of the twitter will appear in the logoutbutton.my code for that is

```
- (void) OAuthTwitterController: (SA_OAuthTwitterController *) controller authenticatedWithUsername: (NSString *) username {
    NSLog(@"Authenicated for %@", username);
 [_btntwitterLogeout setTitle:username forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

but i want to set a condition if the `_btntwitterLogeout.title = nil` then ……. do some thing
but i didnt know how to set condition if there is no title in the logout button.
i put this code,but no luck

```
if (_btntwitterLogeout.titleLabel.text == nil) {
            _btntwitterLogeout.hidden = YES;
            _btnTwitter.hidden=NO;
        }
        else {
            _btntwitterLogeout.hidden = NO;
            _btnTwitter.hidden=YES;
        }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @Hot Licks the _btntwitterLogeout.hidden = YES;
            _btnTwitter.hidden=NO; it is not working .

Comment: @HotLicks i want to hide +btntwitterlogeout and unhide _btntwitter if the _btntwitterlogeout has no title

Comment: As Inder suggests, the title may be a "null string" rather than `nil` -- debugging or using NSLog would tell you.  And are you sure that both of your button ivars are connected to the actual buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
if (btntwitterLogeout.titleLabel.text.length == 0)
{

    _btntwitterLogeout.hidden = YES;
    _btnTwitter.hidden=NO;
}
else
{

    _btntwitterLogeout.hidden = NO;
    _btnTwitter.hidden=YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one....

```
if ([_btntwitterLogeout.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    _btntwitterLogeout.hidden = YES;
    _btnTwitter.hidden=NO;
}
else {
    _btntwitterLogeout.hidden = NO;
    _btnTwitter.hidden=YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (![_btntwitterLogeout.titleLabel.text isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    _btntwitterLogeout.hidden = YES;
    _btnTwitter.hidden=NO;
}
else {
    _btntwitterLogeout.hidden = NO;
    _btnTwitter.hidden=YES;
}
```

it's better approach rather checking length of Title string

Comment: it's better approach rather checking length of Title string

Comment: in your answer not in comment section so will you do the same in your answer ....